# This site or app is sending too much traffic to rawgit.com.

Tags: notifications, web

This site or app is sending too much traffic to rawgit.com. Please contact its owner and ask them to use cdn.rawgit.com instead, which has no traffic limit.

I am getting this above notification on my website. Can anyone help me to resolve out this issue.How I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Rawgit has two Domains for displaying your Github files:

- `cdn.rawgit.com` is for when you request that site a lot (Updates take a while to show).
- `rawgit.com` is for testing (Updates are visible immediately).

You need to use the `cdn.rawgit.com` link as you are sending to much traffic.

For example:

`https://rawgit.com/Oisins/Mod/master/.project`
becomes
`https://cdn.rawgit.com/Oisins/Mod/master/.project`

See http://rawgit.com/ for more info.